# the trait bound is not satisfied error in library

Tags: random, rust, traits

I am trying to generate a keypair using secp256k1 library.

In the official documentation I found this code:

```
use rand::OsRng;
use secp256k1::{Secp256k1, Message};

let secp = Secp256k1::new();
let mut rng = OsRng::new().expect("OsRng");
let (secret_key, public_key) = secp.generate_keypair(&mut rng);
```

And I put this in my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.6.1"

[dependencies.secp256k1]
features = ["rand"]
version = "0.12.0"
```

However, I get this compile error:

```
| secp.generate_keypair(&mut rng);
|      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `secp256k1::rand::Rng` is not implemented for 
                        `std::result::Result<rand::rngs::OsRng, rand::Error>`
```

I am very new to Rust and I am trying to understand it but I find it extremely difficult. Please explain what is my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: I have copied your code and get a different error: _"no method named `generate_keypair` found for type `secp256k1::Secp256k1<secp256k1::All>` in the current scope"_. Please provide a [mcve], including crate versions, so that the same error can be obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a crate version mismatch. The latest version of the `rand` crate is `0.6.1`, but `secp256k1 0.12.0` depends on a much older version - `0.4.3`.

A quick fix is to use an older version of `rand`:

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.4.3"
```

And consider asking the authors of `secp256k1` to update their dependencies.

The way that I found this was to search in the `Cargo.lock` file, which contains all of the actual versions of dependencies used by your application.

Comment: *search in the Cargo.lock file* — the duplicate describes a more automated way to find this error.

Comment: *to update their dependencies* — I'd ask them to increase the version range, specifically. Presumably their code can support versions 0.4 through 0.6 of rand.